# NSUserDefaults not saving in memory in simulator on Jenkins

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, nsuserdefaults, simulator

I'm having this odd situation where the NSUserDefaults works fine on real devices, but not on the simulators of one particular mac we have.

registerDefaults works fine:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["Default1": 3, "Default2: false])
```

If I run `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dictionaryRepresentation()`, these default values were included in the dictionary.

However, `setObject` doesn't work

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("abc", for Key: "ABC")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ABC")` will always return nil on simulator.

The mac has this problem is running El Capitan as a Jenkins CI Server (as Launch Agent), and  I've tried to run the app on different versions of simulators (9.2, 8.4...etc) without any luck so far. Any thoughts?

Comment: What about `setValue` method, does it work ?

Comment: @Wongzigii `setValue` doesn't work too.

Comment: The key is case sensitive.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and reinstalling Xcode and all of the Xcode related files in the Library folder on that Mac?

Comment: @DaveBatton Yes, tried to delete xcode completely and reinstall, still not working.

Comment: I figured if I log out from Jenkins and switching to a normal user, I will be able to use NSUserDefaults. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've run into a similar situation ourselves, and before we went for a full on reinstall of the OS (`El Capitan`), we decided to try just creating a new user `Jenkins2` as a proper real user, that lives in `/Users/Jenkins2`, rather than the *nux-style install that lived in `/Users/Shared/Jenkins`.  After working through a lot of the kinks that came with permission changing, and moving files, this solved the problem for us.

Versions: OSX `El Capitan`, Jenkins v. `1.652` and XCode `7.2.1`.

If you're at your wits end, I'd suggest to try get a simple repro project that definitely doesn't work under Jenkins, and then verify it also doesn't work outside of Jenkins, in XCode, but when logged in as the Jenkins user.  If so, it's likely you're hitting the same problem as us.  Create a new user, in the default Mac way, and try that same project there.  If that's a satisfiable solution to you, move all the Jenkins setup to that new user, and delete the old.  That's what we've ended up doing, and we haven't had an issue since.